# python BaseHTTPRequestHandler and local http server directory for opening file

Tags: python, directory, httpserver, basehttprequesthandler

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        #path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.path)   --> Not work !
        with open(self.path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as File:
            content = File.read()


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=8085):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print ('Starting httpd...')
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Hello,
I'm trying to manipulate a file using a BaseHTTPRequestHandler and a local HTTP server.
I can't get the absolute path, really weird stuff. I'm using `os.path.join` with `os.getcwd`, and it will always return this kind of directory : `c:\\path.ext` instead of `c:\\user\\name\\blabla\\path.ext`
I'm working on windows.

Hope someone can help, it seem that the server directory is always at the base root of 'C:'.
Thanks

Comment: cwd of the process is inherited. If your cmd is at C:\ and you start your server like `python c:\user\name\blabla\serv.py`, then cwd is C:\. Ether change your cwd in cmd (`cd c:\user\name\blabla\ `), hardcode `c:\\user\\name\\blabla\\ ` as path in your app, or look at `__file__` and calculate your paths relative to the location of current python file.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation about inheritance, It will allow me to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the cwd directory didn't change at all : printing os.getcwd() in my function do_GET or just after if `__name__ == '__main__'` give the same result.

The real problem was about usage of `os.path.join`, or simply when using something like `open(self.path)`. `self.path` give a string with this format `/path.ext`, and I needed to remove slash...

`os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '/a_second_path')` will return a string with format like `c:/a_second_path`, with truncating for example `users/name/desktop` of cwd.